# How to use Middleware in Multiple Login system

Tags: laravel-5

I have MUltiple login in laravel 5 with using differeent different controller like that Account controller and Admin controller . i want to use Middleware on route for authorize the user. what can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create the `AdminLoggedInMiddleware`

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminLoggedInMiddleware
```

Step 2: Register `AdminLoggedInMiddleware` in `app\Http\Kernel.php` in the `protected $routeMiddleware` array.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminLoggedInMiddleware',
];
```

Step 3: Check if Admin is logged in, so, open `AdminLoggedInMiddleware` and replace the default `handle` method with this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Change this condition as per your requirement.
    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role === 'administrator' ) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Step 4: Open your `AdminController.php` file and add the following method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Similarly, you can create the other middleware for your other user(s) and check if they are logged in or not.

Comment: @user3514160,thank you it helped me to get some idea about middleware authentication.can you explain more detail about the method handle

Comment: @AvineshMathur check out the laracasts video about middleware: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/16