# How middleware works in user multiple login in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php

i read many topics regarding middleware in multiple authentication still i didn't got how exactly works.below is the ref question where stack overflow user explain better way.if any one know about multiple authentication user login in laravel please post your answers.thank you.

Ref:

[How to use Middleware in Multiple Login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312915/how-to-use-middleware-in-multiple-login-system)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel used to this with route filters and groups. You would set a group of routes to run with a specific filter. I have also made an answer about middle ware. see if this helps [Roles with laravel 5, how to allow only admin access to some root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060925/roles-with-laravel-5-how-to-allow-only-admin-access-to-some-root/29061489#29061489)

You would make multiple middlewares, with various checks in.